# How to prove a theorem about the expectation of a function?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I‘m very lost about this problem: Let $X$ be a nonnegative random variable and $f$ be a monotone increasing, differentiable function.
Show that:

$$\mathbb E[f(X)]=f(0)+\int_{0}^{\infty}f’(s)P(X>s)\mathrm d s$$

I have unfortunately no background in measure theory at all.

Comment: No measures needed. Hint: write a double integral and exchange the order.

Comment: @SeanRoberson That wouldn't be legal. You definitely require measure theory for this.

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$
f(X)-f(0) = \int_0^X f'(s)\ \mathsf ds=\int_0^\infty f'(s)\mathsf 1_{\{X>s\}}\ \mathsf ds.
$$
Taking the expectation yields
\begin{align}
E[f(X)-f(0)] &= \mathbb E\left[ \int_0^\infty f'(s)\mathsf 1_{\{X>s\}}\ \mathsf ds\right]\\ &=\int_0^\infty f'(s)\mathbb E[\mathsf 1_{\{X>s\}}]\ \mathsf ds\\ &= \int_0^\infty f'(s)\mathbb P(X>s)\ \mathsf ds,
\end{align}
as was to be shown. Note that moving the expectation inside of the integral is justified by Tonelli's theorem.